# Can a Cordova app securely edit google spreadsheets?

Tags: cordova, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

does anyone know if this is possible and whether the workflow is correct? I'm a bit lost in the massive Google Apps Platform...

I want to create a Cordova app where a user logs in with their Google credentials. These credentials are used to securely create a Google docs spreadsheet on their Google drive. Users could then upload photos and text to this spreadsheet.

I want to do all this with JavaScript.

Should I be sending Ajax requests from the Cordova app to a stand alone Google Apps Script to Authenticate and then edit the spreadsheet?

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Drive SDK only allows for the import and export of Google Sheets; not complex or in-place manipulations of the content. While Apps Script does allow for this, it is not possible to reliably consume it as a service from an outside system. You may be able to patch something together, but I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: Hi Eric, appreciate the response. Could you expand a little on 'reliably consume'? I realise sheet manipulation is not part of drive SDK - am I looking at a non-JavaScript external intermediary , say in .NET, to manipulate data in the sheets?

Comment: The [Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) would allow you to do in-place manipulations. It's built on our older API stack (gdata) and has somewhat limited functionality (can't do formatting, etc), but this usage would be within its intended purpose. 

You could Apps Script to manipulate the spreadsheet, publish is as a web app, and then make requests to that web app from another application. However, authentication would be an issue, since Apps Script web apps don't support OAuth2.